# Brew install python3 cannot on macOS 10.9

Tags: python, macos, installation, homebrew

I tried to use brew install python3 on macOS 10.9, but I got error as below, what can I do? Can you help me? By the way, I am using a macmini 2009 late, do I have upgrade my MacOS to 10.10 or 10.11, I am not sure what is the highest version for my macmini...

```
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).

==> Installing dependencies for python: sphinx-doc, gdbm, makedepend, openssl, readline, sqlite, xz
==> Installing python dependency: sphinx-doc
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/54/4ef326d0c654da1ed91341a7a1f43efc18a8c770ddd2b8e45df97cb79d82/Sphinx-1.7.8.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/mi/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/7724e7147d6bde066d1f33877c84313f0022f9e968578891746ce90feb85f567--Sphinx-1.7.8.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/1d/201c13e353956a1c840f5d0fbf041bd45bbd678ea4843ebf25924e8984c/setuptools-40.2.0.zip
Already downloaded: /Users/mi/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/16d798a247946c3552651aa8f309c94303bdc666a9598610c65187e5da345a77--setuptools-40.2.0.zip
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.8/libexec/vendor --single-version-externally-managed --record=installed.txt
Last 15 lines from /Users/mi/Library/Logs/Homebrew/sphinx-doc/01.python: 2018-09-05 22:19:48 +0900

python
-c
import setuptools, tokenize
__file__ = 'setup.py'
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec')) --no-user-cfg install
--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/sphinx-doc/1.7.8/libexec/vendor
--single-version-externally-managed
--record=installed.txt

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!

Error: You are using macOS 10.9.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures and other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's
GitHub, Discourse, Twitter or IRC. As you are running this old version,
you are responsible for resolving any issues you experience.
```

Comment: I think its just like it said at bottom. you have an old version of the MaxOS.  I don't know what the latest version works on the  Mac mini is but I would try to upgrade to the latest and see if that helps.  Have you considered using Anaconda distribution of python?  Its a nice package if you are new to python. It also makes it easy to use virtual environments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I decide to try `macOS 64-bit installer for OS X 10.9 and later` on `https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/`. By the way, what is different from python3 and Anaconda python5.2?

Comment: Anaconda version may be 5.2 but Python version with Anaconda, is 2.7 or 3.6.